# Find the largest integer k such that 3^k < N

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to find the largest power of 3 that is less than a given number. My algorithm passes all tests but times out on the final test (codewars doesn't show me what the failing test case is unfortunately).

I figured that finding the square root of the number and working backwards would be the fastest way... then I decided to use the cubed root and work backwards (is my thinking correct?).

So what I ended up with is this:

```
def largest_power(number):
    for index in range(int(number ** (1.0 / 3.0)), -1, -1):
        if 3 ** index < number:
            return index
    return -1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = largest_power(100)
    print(result)
```

This still times out on one unknown test case.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Thank you for taking the time to look.

EDIT:

I am now trying using the logarithm technique as mentioned in the comments. This works, but is actually failing a few test cases. For example if N = 3 it expects 0 for an answer (not 1).

Hardcoding a check for  the number 3 passes that one bad test:

```
def largest_power(number):
    if number == 3:
        return 0
    return int(log(number, 3))
```

but now I see a couple other failures. It doesn't show what is failing unfortunately:
[image]

Comment: Base-3 logarithm should give you the answer (assuming correct rounding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @interjay in the comments, you could try computing the base-3 logarithm and then rounding down:

```
>>> import math
>>> N = 1234
>>> int(math.log(N, 3))
6
```

And, indeed, 6 is the largest `k` as 7 is too much:

```
>>> 3 ** 6
729
>>> 3 ** 7
2187
```

This uses floating-point math, so it may be imprecise for very large `N`.

Comment: Yes I have been trying this way since seeing the above comment... oddly enough it fails some test cases. For example if N is 3 it expects 0: ```test.assert_equals(largest_power(3), 0)``` but the above gives 1 as an answer. There's a few others that fail too but I cannot see the actual test case being used hmmm. I am wondering if these test cases are actually incorrect.

Comment: Right! The "Large cases" test is definitely correct - the snippet above indeed gives the wrong result for N=81, and also for N=3. You may be able to fix both by starting at the base-3 logarithm and then decreasing `k` by 1 until the result is small enough.

Comment: Okay sounds good... I will mark this right as I believe it's the correct way

Answer (score 3):

`if 3 ** index < number` is expensive to run in  an iteration. I got the tests to pass by using a base that starts at 1 and keeps multiplying by 3, keeping track of how many times. This would be a logarithmic time answer.

Comment: I know this is overkill, but you could actually do it in log(log(N)) steps, if you double the index each time, building up a list of powers `3^(2^x)`, and then greedily take products (largest-fit-first). The sum of the exps is the overall exp.